# Stripping all tag attributes from a HTML string except style

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a form where users can enter descriptions, using TinyMCE for styling. Because of this, my users have the ability to insert HTML. I am already stripping almost all HTML elements using `strip_tags`, but users can still input malicious values, such as this one:

`<strong onclick="window.location='http://example.com'">Evil</strong>`

I would like to prevent users from being able to do this, by stripping all attributes from all tags, except for the `style` attribute.

I can only find solutions to strip either all attributes, or strip only the specified ones. I would like to keep only the `style` attribute.

I have tried DOMDocument, but it seems to add `DOCTYPE` and `html` tags on its own, outputting it as an entire HTML document. Additionally, it sometimes seems to randomly add HTML entities such as upside-down question marks.

Here's my DOMDocument implementation:

```
//Example "evil" input
$description = "<p><strong onclick=\"alert('evil');\">Evil</strong></p>";

//Strip all tags from description except these
$description = strip_tags($description, '<p><br><a><b><i><u><strong><em><span><sup><sub>');

//Strip attributes from tags (to prevent inline Javascript)
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($description);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element)
{
    //Attributes cannot be removed directly because DOMNamedNodeMap implements Traversable incorrectly
    //Atributes are first saved to an array and then looped over later
    $attributes_to_remove = array();
    foreach($element->attributes as $name => $value)
    {
        if($name != 'style')
        {
            $attributes_to_remove[] = $name;
        }
    }

    //Loop over saved attributes and remove them
    foreach($attributes_to_remove as $attribute)
    {
        $element->removeAttribute($attribute);
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two options for DOMDocument::loadHtml() that will solve the problem.

```
$dom->loadHTML($description,  LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

But they are only available in libxml >= 2.7.8. If you have an older version you can try a different approach:

If you know that you expect a fragment you can use that and save only the children of the `body` element.

```
$description = <<<'HTML'
<strong onclick="alert('evil');" style="text-align:center;">Evil</strong>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($description);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element) {
    $attributes_to_remove = iterator_to_array($element->attributes);
    unset($attributes_to_remove['style']);
    foreach($attributes_to_remove as $attribute => $value) {
        $element->removeAttribute($attribute);
    }
}
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes as $node) {
  echo $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
```

Output:

```
<strong style="text-align:center;">Evil</strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is more or less what you mean to do...

```
$description = "<p><strong onclick=\"alert('evil');\">Evil</strong></p>";
$description = strip_tags( $description, '<p><br><a><b><i><u><strong><em><span><sup><sub>' );

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML( $description );
$tags=$dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach( $tags as $tag ){
    if( $tag->hasAttributes() ){
        $attributes=$tag->attributes;
        foreach( $attributes as $name => $attrib ) $tag->removeAttribute( $name );
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
/* Will echo out `Evil` in bold but without the `onclick` */
```

Comment: This is pretty much equivalent to the code I posted earlier. My code (and your code) inserts HTML entities and `html` and `body` tags, which is what I'm trying to prevent. I need a solution that doesn't use DOMDocument and does not attempt to "fix" the HTML (because the HTML is not meant to be an entire document).

Comment: To be fair I ran this code in an existing page and found no problems - when I ran it simply "as is" with no existing html markup I found, like you say, that it had added all the HTML markup for itself.